# Uncaught TypeError: this._input.charCodeAt is not a function

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-cli

I created an Angular 2 project using Angular 2 CLI and used `ng build --prod` command and got no errors.

When I upload the `dist` folder into my website, I get the following error when the app loads:

[image]

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._input.charCodeAt is not a function_Tokenizer._advance @ main .688167 c….bundle.js: 1716 _Tokenizer @ main .688167 c….bundle.js: 1716 tokenize @ main .688167 c….bundle.js: 1709 Parser.parse @ main .688167 c….bundle.js: 219 HtmlParser.parse @ main .688167 c….bundle.js: 380 DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeLoadedTemplate @ main .688167 c….bundle.js: 598 DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplateSync @ main .688167 c….bundle.js: 598 DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeDirective @ main .688167 c….bundle.js: 598 RuntimeCompiler._createCompiledTemplate @ main .688167 c….bundle.js: 1090(anonymous
function) @ main .688167 c….bundle.js: 1090(anonymous
function) @ main .688167 c….bundle.js: 1090 RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents @ main .688167 c….bundle.js: 1090 RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ main .688167 c….bundle.js: 1090 RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ main .688167 c….bundle.js: 1090 PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone @ main .688167 c….bundle.js: 717 PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule @ main .688167 c….bundle.js: 717(anonymous
function) @ main .688167 c….bundle.js: 1509 __webpack_require__ @ inline.js: 1(anonymous
function) @ main .688167 c….bundle.js: 2131 __webpack_require__ @ inline.js: 1 window.webpackJsonp @ inline.js: 1(anonymous
function) @ main .688167 c….bundle.js: 1
```

I'm using the latest Angular 2 CLI with webpack and Angular 2 RC.7

What could have gone wrong?

The `this._input.charCodeAt` is only used in the angular compiler folder as below:
[image]

Comment: Care to share your code? :P

Comment: next time, please format the stacktrace properly so we don't have to do it ourselves

Comment: @rinukkusu App with more than 20 components.. I don't think so..

Comment: @mic4ael I'm sorry, I added a screenshot.

Comment: I never typed this in my app, that's why I have no idea what to do in this case. @rinukkusu

Comment: I just realized that looking through the trace! (now that it's readable)

Comment: can you run `grep -r 'this\._input\.charCodeAt' *`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Windows. If you want to know where Ican find the `chatCodeAt` function, I see it only in the @angular/compiler files. I added an image to see all search results of this line

Answer (score 49):

Might be caused by loading component code instead of template, i.e.

```
templateUrl: 'my.component'
```

instead of

```
templateUrl: 'my.component.html'
```

Comment: Just came by to say that saved my day.

Comment: Also saved my day!

Answer (score 10):

The raw-loader has changed. You have to use **.default** when requiring the xlf file.

```
const translations = require('raw-loader!./i18n/messages.ko.xlf').default;
```

I faced same issue when I have updated @ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill to version 1.0.0 in my angular project. And issue has fixed when I implemented above changes

Refer: [ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill Issue#60](https://github.com/ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill/issues/60)

Comment: Where to put it ? It is not quite obvious ...

Answer (score 0):

A following debug code helped me a lot to find out which template was incorrectly imported.

Inject a next snippet to compiler's `_Tokenizer` in your `./node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js` (or other bundle which are used):

```
function _Tokenizer(_file, _getTagDefinition, _tokenizeIcu, _interpolationConfig) {
    // ...
    try {
        this._advance();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('[Tokenizer Error]: ' + _file && JSON.stringify(_file, null, 2));
        throw e;
    }
}
```

See a screenshot as example:

[image]